# Scope variables don't reflect in template

Tags: angularjs

I have part of an angular app setup as follows:

```
<section >
    <div ng-controller="setHeaderCtrl" class="navbar navbar-default header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsed-bar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand brand-text" ui-sref="index">
                    <span class="sports-text">Sports</span>
                    <span class="gully-text">Gully</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsed-bar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" ng-if="searchingAway">
                    <li class="local-search-cont">
                         <input type="text" class="local-type-top" placeholder="Search">
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li ng-if="!userObject">
                        <a ng-click="showLogin()" class="navbar-txt-block" style="cursor: pointer;">
                            Login
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li ng-if="userObject.user">                                           
                        <a class="navbar-txt-block" ui-sref="home" style="cursor: pointer;">
                            Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li ng-if="userObject">    
                        {{userObject}}                
                        <a class="navbar-txt-block" style="cursor: pointer;">
                            {{userDetails.first_name}} {{userDetails.last_name}}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

and my `setHeaderCtrl` is as follows:

```
app.controller('setHeaderCtrl',['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$state', 'Page', '$modal', 
    function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $state, Page, $modal){
        $rootScope.$on('userSet', function(){
            var authKey = $rootScope.authKey;
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Token '+authKey;
            $http.get('/loginCheck/').success(function(data){
                $scope.userObject = data;
                    $scope.userDetails = data.user;
            });
        });
        $scope.userObject = {}
        $http.get('/loginCheck/').success(function(data){
            $scope.userObject.user = data;
            $scope.userDetails = data.user;
            console.log($scope.userDetails);
        }).error(function(data, status){
            if(status == 401){
                $scope.userObject.user = undefined;
            }
        });
        $rootScope.$on('setAwayHeader', function(){
            $scope.searchingAway = true;
        });
        $rootScope.$on('setIndexHeader', function(){
            $scope.searchingAway = false;
        });
        $scope.showLogin = function(){
            $modal.open({
                windowClass: 'modal fade login-modal', 
                templateUrl: '/static/partials/modals/loginModal.html',
                controller: 'loginCtrl'
            })
        }
    }
])
```

My problem is such that the `{{userObject}}` or `{{userDetails}}` never displays. I can guarantee that there's a response from the server because `console.log` shows the correct data.

Comment: And what exactly should `{{userObject}}` display? `userObject` seems to be an object. So what do you expect to be printed? Btw: one time you have `$scope.userObject = data` and the next time you have `$scope.userObject.user = data;`.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `ng-if="userObject"` is not good, it always true. Replace it by boolean, or by userObject property: `ng-if="userObject.user"`. [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d1ygpLvk/)

Comment: your fiddle link is broken.

Comment: I'm not sure if this solves my problem. The `ng-if` condition gets evaluated but the usage of `{{userDetails.first_name}}` wont' work.